# Calculate $S_2(\varphi(U))$

Tags: integration, analysis, measure-theory, definite-integrals, manifolds

Hey I have a question for this problem:

Let $U := (0, 4) × (0, 2\pi) ⊆ \mathbb{R}^2$ and $\varphi : U → \mathbb{R}^3$ given by $\varphi(r, θ) := (r \cos θ, r \sin θ, r)$.

Calculate $S_2(\varphi(U))$. So for $S_2(\varphi(U))$ I have this formula

$S_2(\varphi(U))=\int_U \det(D\varphi^t \cdot D\varphi)^{1/2}$

The problem is that here calculating $\det(D\varphi^t \cdot D\varphi)$ is really hard so I want to know if there is any trick to speed this up.

What I have done is:

$D\varphi=\left(\begin{matrix}
\cos θ & -r\cos θ \\
\sin θ & r\cos θ \\
1 & 0
\end{matrix}\right)$

And therefore $D\varphi^tD\varphi=\left|\begin{matrix}
2 & -r\cos^2θ+r\cos θ \sin θ \\
-r\cos^2θ+r\cos θ \sin θ & 2r^2\cos^2 θ
\end{matrix}\right|$

And therefore $\det(D\varphi^t \cdot D\varphi)=\frac{1}{4}(6r^2+6r^2\cos 2θ+2r^2\sin 2θ+r^2\sin 4θ)$

It is really a lot of calculation and I wanted to know if there is some other way to "speed" this up and to make it "easier".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't look right. Your $(1,2)$ entry (top right) of $D\phi$ should be $-r\sin a$, so $(D\phi)^tD\phi=\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0\\
 0 & r^2\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: okay thank you so if I proceed I have $\int_{0}^{4}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \sqrt{2}rdθdr$ right? Or have I $\int_{0}^{4}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \sqrt{2}rdθdr+\int_{0}^{4}\int_{0}^{2\pi} -\sqrt{2}rdθdr$

Comment: @MarcoDiGiacomo yup, so $2\pi \sqrt{2}\frac{4^2}{2}=16\sqrt{2}\pi$.

Comment: Or have I $\int_{0}^{4}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \sqrt{2}rdθdr+\int_{0}^{4}\int_{0}^{2\pi} -\sqrt{2}rdθdr$

Comment: where are you getting this new thing from? is that really what you meant to write? look closely at what you wrote. it is obviously 0. Your original was right.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)